# Get name of attached debugger

Tags: c#, debugging

I would like to know if it's possible to not only get weither a debugger is attached or not (

```cs
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached
```

) but also it's name (Something like

```cs
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Assembly.GetName()
```

).

Comment: It's a different process that you can't cross without hacks. Do you have any other debuggers beside Visual Studio?